# I have errors when I try to remove an item from Array in Elasticsearch field using script

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm trying to remove an item from my elasticsearch array field but it gives me this error:

> ERROR =>  TransportError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', '[D3e7NWc][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/write/update[s]]')

### I just want to remove this item from the array

```
{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "customers",
                "_type": "customer",
                "_id": "QOTzXMUcrnbsYyFKeouHnjlkjQB3",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "uid": "QOTzXMUcrnbsYyFKeouHnjlkjQB3",
                    "email": "georgehatouts@gmail.com",
                    "favorites": [
                        "AV8My20P8yrUSAV2Zp6C",
                        "AV8Mw5zq8yrUSAV2Zp6A"  <--- I WANT TO REMOVE THIS ITEM
                    ],
                    "history": [],
                    "settings": {},
                    "purchases": [],
                    "created": 1508083496773,
                    "updated": 1508083496773
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here's my python code:

```
def remove_fav_product(uid, product_id):
    ''' Remove favorite product from customer favorites '''

    print('Start removing favorite product')
    print('UID => ', uid)
    print('product_id => ', product_id)

    # 1st check if the user has this product on favorites,
    # 2nd if the user doesn't have this remove it from the list

    timestamp = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

    doc = {
        "script" : {
            "inline":"ctx._source.favorites.remove(params.product_id)",
            "params":{
                "product_id":product_id
            }
        }
    }

    es.update(index="customers", doc_type='customer', id=uid, body=doc)
    es.indices.refresh(index="customers")
    return jsonify({'message': 'customer_remove_fav_product'}), 200
#end
```

But when I try to add new item in the array is works

```
def add_favevorite_product(uid, fav_product):
    ''' Add new favorite product '''

    print('Start new favorite product')
    product_id = fav_product['products']

    # 1st check if the user has this product on favorites,
    # 2nd if the user doesn't have this remove it from the list

    timestamp = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

    doc = {
        "script" : {
            "inline":"ctx._source.favorites.add(params.product_id)",
            "params":{
                "product_id":product_id
            }
        }
    }

    es.update(index="customers", doc_type='customer', id=uid, body=doc)
    es.indices.refresh(index="customers")
    return jsonify({'message': 'customer_updated'}), 200
#end
```

Yet when I try to add `script.inline: on` AND `script.indexed: on` in my elasticsearch.yml but I am not sure if this is ok, look at the last 2 lines on the bottom, is that good?

```
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
#cluster.name: my-application
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
#node.name: node-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
#path.data: /path/to/data
#
# Path to log files:
#
#path.logs: /path/to/logs
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
#network.host: 127.0.0.1
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
#http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when new node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
#discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
#
# Prevent the "split brain" by configuring the majority of nodes (total number of master-eligible nodes / 2 + 1):
#
#discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, consult the zen discovery module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
#
# Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
#
#gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, consult the gateway module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: true

#script.inline: on
#script.indexed: on
```

Comment: Any help guys is gonna help me

Comment: The remove function of Arrays in here "ctx._source.favorites.remove(params.product_id)" accepts index of the Array Element to be removed not the value. To remove an element from Array, you need to find its index.

Comment: Thnx bro can you tell me how i can find the index of the value

Comment: Working on it..

Comment: Thnx i gona upvote or your answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Embed this command into your code and see if this works.

```
POST test/array/1/_update
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "for(int i=0;i<ctx._source.favorites.size();i++){if(ctx._source.favorites[i]==params.product_id){ctx._source.favorites.remove(i)}}",
    "params": {
      "product_id": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: oups i get this error > ERROR =>  TransportError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', '[script] unknown field [source], parser not found')

Comment: Which version of ES you are using?

Comment: Bro Worksssssssssssss

Comment: God Bless you bro

Comment: God Bless you too buddy.

Answer (score 1):

For your example, the easiest way to remove an element from a list that matches a specific value is to use the "removeIf" method. The code below will remove the product id matching the string under params.

```
POST test/array/1/_update

{"script":{"lang":"painless","source":"ctx._source.favorites.removeIf(e -> e.equals(params.product_id))","params":{"product_id":"AV8Mw5zq8yrUSAV2Zp6A"}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thnx to Hatim Stovewala I just add this code

```
doc = {
        "script" : {
            "inline": "for(int i=0;i<ctx._source.favorites.size();i++){if(ctx._source.favorites[i]==params.product_id){ctx._source.favorites.remove(i)}}",
            "lang": "painless",
            "params":{
                "product_id":product_id
            }
        }
    }
```